# ROR + HAML radio button issue for displaying readonly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

HAML code to generate radioButton:

```
= radio_button_tag 'options', "internal", :checked => @option_value==2 ? true : nil,
:disabled =>@option_value!=2 ? nil : true
```

HTML code for above HAML:

```
<input type="radio" value="" name="options" id="options_external" checked="checked">
```

My requirements are:

1. RadioButton has to be readonly.
2. According to @option_value, radiobutton has to checked or unchecked. For example, above code has to be checked when @option_value=2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= radio_button_tag 'options', "internal", @option_value == 2 ,
:disabled => @option_value == 2
```

The main differences:

1) You don't need to check the value of @option_value == 2 through a ternary operator, @option_value == 2 will return true or false, which is what you want.

2) :checked is not part of the optional hash in radio_button_tag, as seen [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag).

Comment: @Mike : Thanx, But I am not getting checked radio button while applying your code.

Comment: It should work, if you substitute @option_value == 2 for the true value for example, it should become checked.

Comment: Yes, I got it, Can you please help to make checkbox of same functionality.

Comment: What is the value of @option_value when you call the radio_button_tag method? Can you post more code?

Comment: @Mike : SampleCode For Checkbox : = check_box_tag 'options', 'lowcost', @option_value == 1, :disabled => @option_value != 1. Here I wanna setup readonly condition, so How can I add this one ?

Comment: Oh I see. So it would be = check_box_tag 'options', 'lowcost', @option_value == 1, :disabled => @option_value == 1 ... assuming you want to mimic the same functionality as the radio button.